# Referencing child nodes in schema, particularly for item_lookup_field

Tags: mongodb, eve

I have a MongoDB I'm referencing with results that looks like this:

```
"_items": [
    {
        ...
        "_id": 2014318,
        ...
        "value": {
             "UniqueID":2014318,
             "Data":{...}
        }
    },
    {
        ...
        "_id": 2014319,
        ...
        "value": {
             "UniqueID":2014319,
             "Data":{...}
        }
    }, ...
]
```

I'm having two issues, the first is that it seems eve's item resolution breaks down if the `_id` field isn't a mongoID. Because I can't reference this collection with `http://.../item/2014318` like I'd expect.

Second is that I can't figure out how to access `value['UniqueID']` to manually set the lookup field that I want to use.

Any thoughts or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the type of the `_id` field, you need to change it in the `DOMAIN` dict. (I don't recommend this)

You could create a new field (`my_id`) to use for lookups.

There are two ways of having a non-standard lookup field (See [Item endpoints](http://python-eve.org/config.html#resource-item-endpoints)):

- `additional_lookup` for creating a second read-only endpoint, or
- `item_lookup_field` to define a field that acts like `_id`.

You also have to adjust the `ITEM_URL`-setting for a non-ObjectId identifier.

Hope this helps.